# Select multiple items using "shift" key

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I use select2 v.3.5.1 and need to select multiple items. I wonder, is it possible to select multiple items using `shift` key? I don't want to have a `multiple select`, just select a few options while holding `shift` key. A code snippet is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by holding the ctrl key.
Thats the default key to press if you're picking individual items in a list in other programs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the answer a possible solution can be based on:

- add a **data-maxitem** to your select
- add a delegated event listener in order to detect the shit key when selecting
- on **select2-selecting** test if the event must be prevented
- at the end write the result into the div

```js
$(document).on('keyup keydown', ".select2-drop-active", function (e) {
    console.log('shift: ' + e.shiftKey);
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        $("#mySelect1").attr('multiple', 'multiple');
    } else {
        $("#mySelect1").removeAttr('multiple');
    }
})
$("#mySelect1").select2()
        .on('select2-selecting', function (e) {
            var maxItem = $('#mySelect1').data('maxitem');
            var shiftKey = $("#mySelect1").attr('multiple') == 'multiple';
            var seletedOpt = $('.select2-drop-active .mySelected').length;
            console.log('maxItem: ' + maxItem + ' shiftKey: ' + shiftKey + ' seletedOpt: ' + seletedOpt);
            if (shiftKey && seletedOpt < maxItem) {
                $('.select2-drop-active .select2-highlighted').addClass('mySelected');
                if ($('.select2-drop-active .mySelected').length >= maxItem) {
                    $("#mySelect1").removeAttr('multiple');
                    var selectedOption = $('.select2-drop-active .mySelected').map(function (idx, ele) {
                            return ele.textContent;
                    }).get().join(' ');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.select2-container a span:first').text(selectedOption);
                    }, 100, selectedOption);
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            } else {
                $("#mySelect1").removeAttr('multiple');
            }
        });
```

```css
.mySelected {
    background: #3875d7;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/master/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/master/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="mySelect1" data-maxitem="2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish this in 2022.  I searched extensively, and none of the solutions quite worked for me, probably due to changes in the latest version of select2, I suspect.  After much experimentation, I came up with a solution that works, and it also works when you have multiple select2 widgets on the same page.

The solution will set each select2 widget on the page to select each item between two items, by holding down the shift key.  You can release the shift key after selecting the first item, in case you need to scroll or something, as long as you hold it down again before clicking the second item.  It works whether you select the first item as the one farther down in the list or the one higher up in the list.  You can select multiple, separate blocks of items by releasing shift and holding it down again before clicking another set of items (so you could quickly select, say, items 1-5, 9-15, and 20-25), with 6 clicks.

It also requires that each select2 has an id, and is given the class "select2multiplewidget" (or you could use some other shared class name if you modified the javascript code below)

Note that I am using Django in my app, so it is possible that the specific class names being used are from Django's implementation, though I doubt this is the case.

**Javascript code to add** (my solution)

```
var count_shift = 0;
var shift_array = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
   //
   // Tell your app whether or not the shift key is being held down
   $('.select2-search__field').on('keydown', function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 16) {
           isShiftDown = true;
       }
   }).on('keyup', function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 16) {
           isShiftDown = false;
       }
   });
   
   // This event is used when the text box doesn't have focus.
   $(window).on("keydown", function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 16) {
           isShiftDown = true;
       }
   }).on("keyup", function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 16) {
           isShiftDown = false;
       }
   });
   
   //
   // Event handlers to select a range of items
   $('.select2multiplewidget').each(function() {
      $(this).on('select2:closing', function () {
          // To be exact, there's no need to return true.
          return !isShiftDown;
      }).on("select2:select", function (e) {
        if (isShiftDown) {
           var _id = $(document).find('li.select2-results__option--highlighted').attr('data-select2-id');
           var _n = parseInt(_id.split('-')[4]);
           shift_array.push({ 
              id: _id, 
              data: e.params.data,
              n: _n
           });
           count_shift++;
        }
        
        //
        // This part is allowing you to click either the lowest or highest item first and create the range from either direction.
        if (count_shift == 2) {
           var lower = (shift_array[0].n < shift_array[1].n ? shift_array[0].n : shift_array[1].n);
           var higher = (shift_array[1].n > shift_array[0].n ? shift_array[1].n : shift_array[0].n);
           
           //
           // Get current selections
           var curVals = $(this).val();
           for(var i = lower+1; i < higher; i++)
              curVals.push(i.toString());
           $(this).val(curVals);
           
           $('#select2-' + this.id + '-results').find('.select2-results__option').each(function() {
              var thisn = parseInt($(this).attr('data-select2-id').split('-')[4]);
              if((thisn > lower) && (thisn < higher)) {
                 $(this).attr('aria-selected', 'true');
              }
           });
           $(this).trigger("change");
           $(this).select2('close');
           count_shift = 0;
           shift_array = [];
        }
      });
   });
});
```

**forms.py in Django.**  This is generating a series of select2 multiple dropdowns to specify region groupings of states or DMAs or counties.  This is provided as an example of how the field could be defined and is in the context of a larger process.  It is a snippet from a form factory function that generates the project form class

```
i = 0
while i < instance.num_regions:
    self.fields[f'region_definition_{i}'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label="",
        help_text="Select all of the states to include in this region.  You can select multiple at once by holding control or shift.  Filter the list by typing into the field.",
        widget=Select2MultipleWidget(attrs={
            'data-maxitem': len(STATE_CHOICES), 
            'multiple': 'multiple'
        }), 
        choices=STATE_CHOICES,
        initial=([] if (len(instance.region_definitions) < i+1) else models.mask_region_choices(STATE_CHOICES, instance.region_definitions[i].split(','))),
        required=True,
    )
```

Below I've provided the HTML source code and code from inspect element, for reference, and so this answer is useful beyond the context of Django:

**HTML *source code* resulting from template rendering**

```
<div class="form-group col-xl-5" > 
  <div id="div_id_region_label_0" class="form-group"> 
    <div class=""> 
      <input type="text" name="region_label_0" value="Northeast" maxlength="50" minlength="2" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_region_label_0"> 
      <small id="hint_id_region_label_0" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the reporting label for this region.</small> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group col-xl-5" > 
  <div id="div_id_region_definition_0" class="form-group"> 
    <div class=""> 
      <select name="region_definition_0" lang="None" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-theme="default" data-allow-clear="false" data-maxitem="48" multiple class="select2multiplewidget form-control custom-select django-select2" required id="id_region_definition_0"> 
        <option value="1">Alabama</option> <option value="2">Alaska</option> 
        <option value="3">Arizona</option> <option value="7" selected>Connecticut</option> 
        <option value="8">Delaware</option> <option value="9">Florida</option> 
        <option value="10">Georgia</option> <option value="11">Hawaii</option> 
        <option value="12">Idaho</option> <option value="13">Illinois</option> 
        <option value="14">Indiana</option> <option value="15">Iowa</option> 
        <option value="16">Kansas</option> <option value="17">Kentucky</option> 
        <option value="18">Louisiana</option> <option value="19" selected>Maine</option> 
        <option value="20">Maryland</option> <option value="21" selected>Massachusetts</option> 
        <option value="22">Michigan</option> <option value="23">Minnesota</option> 
        <option value="24">Mississippi</option> <option value="25">Missouri</option> 
        <option value="26">Montana</option> <option value="27">Nebraska</option> 
        <option value="28">Nevada</option> <option value="29" selected>New Hampshire</option> 
        <option value="30" selected>New Jersey</option> <option value="31">New Mexico</option> 
        <option value="32" selected>New York</option> <option value="33">North Carolina</option> 
        <option value="34">North Dakota</option> <option value="35">Ohio</option> 
        <option value="36">Oklahoma</option> <option value="37">Oregon</option> 
        <option value="38" selected>Pennsylvania</option> <option value="39" selected>Rhode Island</option> 
        <option value="40">South Carolina</option> <option value="41">South Dakota</option> 
        <option value="42">Tennessee</option> <option value="43">Texas</option> 
        <option value="44">Utah</option> <option value="45" selected>Vermont</option>
        <option value="46">Virginia</option> <option value="47">Washington</option> 
        <option value="48">Washington DC</option> <option value="49">West Virginia</option> 
        <option value="50">Wisconsin</option> <option value="51">Wyoming</option> 
      </select> 

      <small id="hint_id_region_definition_0" class="form-text text-muted">
        Select all of the states to include in this region.  
        You can select multiple at once by holding control or shift.  
        Filter the list by typing into the field.
      </small> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

**HTML code resulting from template rendering *using Inspect Element*** (I generated mine using the Select2MultipleWidget in forms.py, you can see that at the bottom if it's relevant to you, I am using a form factory function.  This is an example of one of the fields after it is rendered)

```
<div id="div_id_region_definition_0" class="form-group"> <div class=""> 
<select name="region_definition_0" lang="None" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-theme="default" data-allow-clear="false" data-maxitem="48" multiple="" class="select2multiplewidget form-control custom-select django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" required="" id="id_region_definition_0" data-select2-id="id_region_definition_0" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"> 
  <option value="1">Alabama</option> <option value="2">Alaska</option> 
  <option value="3">Arizona</option> <option value="7" selected="" data-select2-id="2">Connecticut</option> 
  <option value="8">Delaware</option> <option value="9">Florida</option> <option value="10">Georgia</option> 
  <option value="11">Hawaii</option> <option value="12">Idaho</option> <option value="13">Illinois</option> 
  <option value="14">Indiana</option> <option value="15">Iowa</option> <option value="16">Kansas</option> 
  <option value="17">Kentucky</option> <option value="18">Louisiana</option> 
  <option value="19" selected="" data-select2-id="3">Maine</option> <option value="20">Maryland</option> 
  <option value="21" selected="" data-select2-id="4">Massachusetts</option> <option value="22">Michigan</option> 
  <option value="23">Minnesota</option> <option value="24">Mississippi</option> 
  <option value="25">Missouri</option> <option value="26">Montana</option> 
  <option value="27">Nebraska</option> <option value="28">Nevada</option> 
  <option value="29" selected="" data-select2-id="5">New Hampshire</option> <option value="30" selected="" data-select2-id="6">New Jersey</option> 
  <option value="31">New Mexico</option> <option value="32" selected="" data-select2-id="7">New York</option> 
  <option value="33">North Carolina</option> <option value="34">North Dakota</option> 
  <option value="35">Ohio</option> <option value="36">Oklahoma</option> 
  <option value="37">Oregon</option> <option value="38" selected="" data-select2-id="8">Pennsylvania</option> 
  <option value="39" selected="" data-select2-id="9">Rhode Island</option> <option value="40">South Carolina</option> 
  <option value="41">South Dakota</option> <option value="42">Tennessee</option> 
  <option value="43">Texas</option> <option value="44">Utah</option> 
  <option value="45" selected="" data-select2-id="10">Vermont</option> <option value="46">Virginia</option> 
  <option value="47">Washington</option> <option value="48">Washington DC</option> <option value="49">West Virginia</option> 
  <option value="50">Wisconsin</option> <option value="51">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 562.5px;"><span class="selection">
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Maine" data-select2-id="472"> 
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Maine</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Massachusetts" data-select2-id="473">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Massachusetts</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="New Hampshire" data-select2-id="474">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>New Hampshire</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="New Jersey" data-select2-id="475">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>New Jersey</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="New York" data-select2-id="476">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>New York</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Pennsylvania" data-select2-id="477">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Pennsylvania</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Rhode Island" data-select2-id="478">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Rhode Island</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Vermont" data-select2-id="479">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Vermont</li>
  <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
    <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
</ul>
</span></span>
<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> 
<small id="hint_id_region_definition_0" class="form-text text-muted">Select all of the states to include in this region.  You can select multiple at once by holding control or shift.  Filter the list by typing into the field.</small> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Hopefully this helps point someone on the right path.  I didn't test this code in a standalone page but it works great in the context of the app I am developing.  It's been in use for almost a year in production and works great!